# Why lambda in rails scope?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, lambda

Why is lambda passed in rails scope? Why not just a typical block? For example:

```
  scope :by_age, lambda do |age|
    joins(:profile).where('profile.age = ?', age) unless age.nil?
  end
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

But it's the same. You just used do ... end syntax instead of {}.

{} and do...end it's just two different syntax, but you can use which you prefer.
Also, lambda has also two different syntax.
One, presented by you, and second:

```
-> { ... your_code ... }
```

or with parameter:

```
->(arg) { ... your_code... }
```

This second syntax looks very nice in scopes.

```
scope :by_age, ->(age) { joins(:profile).where('profile.age = ?', age) unless age.nil? }
```

Answer (score 0):

for named scopes, the block argument is used for extensions. to use a query block, you have to pass it as standard argument (using `lambda`)

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, A Scope can take arguments by using lambda.